# Cannot open a csv file

Tags: pandas, data-science

I  have a csv file on which i need to work in my jupyter notebook ,even though i am able to view the contents in the file using the code in the picture

When i am trying to convert the data into a data frame i get a "no columns to parse from file error"

i have no headers. My csv file looks like this and also i have saved it in the UTF-8 format

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you want to use pandas, you can use [`pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use pandas to read the csv file:

```
df = pd.read_csv("BON3_NC_CUISINES.csv)
print(df)
```